# How to implemt two function using 1 jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm new for jquery..... i have a doubt in the code given below..... if i click the btn the corresponing parent div only should move. Check the code give below. Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready(function(e) { 
         $('.btn').click(function(){ 
             $('.aaa').animate({'left':'500'},500); 
             return false;
         }); 
     });
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <div class="cnt">
      <div class="aaa" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:red; position:relative"></div>
      <a href="#" class="btn">Btn</a>
   </div>
   <div class="cnt">
      <div class="aaa" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:red; position:relative"></div>
      <a href="#" class="btn">Btn</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$(this).prev('.aaa').animate({'left':'500'},500);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) { 
     $('.btn').click(function(){ 
         // the siblings .aaa of this button.
         $(this).siblings('.aaa').animate({'left':'500'},500); 
         return false;
     }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to match the clicked button's previous sibling, which will be the appropriate `<div>` element:

```
 $(".btn").click(function() { 
     $(this).prev().animate({
         left: "500px"
     }, 500); 
     return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn').click(function(){ 
  $('.aaa',this).animate({'left':'500'},500); 
  return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS property LEFT should have a value contains PX suffix

```
$('.aaa').animate({'left':'500'},500); return false;}); });
```

Try updating it to:

```
$('.aaa').animate({'left':'500px'},500)}); return false;});
```